# How to convert from UnityEngine.Transform to Media3d.Transform3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get this error on the last line of code and do not know how to convert

```
 Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Transform' to 'System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Transform3D'
```

This is the code:

```
private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rotire rot = new rotire();
        rot.rotiree();
        mycube.Transform = rot.transform;
    }
```

This is method:

```
public void rotiree()
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(15,40,45)*speed,Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

EDIT:
Rotire class contains a Method to rotate a cube.The name of method is "rotire"

The cube is made in XAML

rotire.cs

```
    using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace WpfApplication6
{
    class Rotire:MonoBehaviour
    {
        float speed=10f;
        public void rotire()
        {
            transform.Rotate(new Vector3(15,40,45)*speed,Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `rotire` class (and why does its name start with a lowercase letter)? What is the class of `mycube`? What type is the `transform` member?

Answer (score 0):

You are wildly mixing Unity and WPF. I don't think that's intended.

Here you create a object based on the Unity MonoBehavior class:

```
rotire rot = new rotire();
```

This seams to be a Media3d Class:

```
mycube
```

And here you try to reference the Unity transform to an Media3d.Transform (WPF Transform) object.

```
mycube.Transform = rot.transform;
```

This cannot work as they are not the same types. You either need to rotate your WPF cube in WPF or your Unity cube in Unity.

Comment: I want to rotate it in Unity (my cube XAML). 
How can I do this?

Comment: So you want to rotate a cube that is defined in xaml. And you want to do this in Unity? I don't think that's possible. You can either rotate your cube in WPF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655033/rotate-3d-cube-in-wpf or you need to create a cube in Unity and rotate it there.